# List comprehension to combine lists with walrus operator

Tags: python-3.x

Can I write this code snippet with a list comprehension?
I've tried to simplify my code as possible.
I'm using the walrus operator and I want to combine the lists.

```py
def odd_generator(num):
    if num % 2:
        return [[num], [-num]]
def test():
    result = []
    for p in range(5):
        if res := odd_generator(p):
            result += res
    return result

print(test())
```

Ouput:

```
[[1], [-1], [3], [-3]]
```

*note: upon further inspection, it seems like I could just return an empty list in my original code and forget about the walrus operator, incorperating the old answer of Marat:*

```
def odd_generator(num):
    if num % 2:
        return [[num], [-num]]
    return []
def test():
    return sum((odd_generator(p) for p in range(5)), start=[])
print(test())
```

Doing some benchmarks to see how well they scale:

```
from itertools import chain
from timeit import timeit
def odd_generator_1(num):
    if num % 2: return list(range(-num, num + 1))
def odd_generator_2(num):
    if num % 2: return list(range(-num, num + 1))
    return []
def test_0(num): return [x for i in range(num) for x in (odd_generator_1(i) or ())]
def test_1(num): return [x for lst in map(odd_generator_1, range(num)) if lst for x in lst]
def test_2(num): return sum((res for p in range(num) if (res := odd_generator_1(p))), start=[])
def test_3(num): return sum((odd_generator_1(p) or [] for p in range(num)), start=[])

def test_4(num): return list(chain.from_iterable(map(odd_generator_2, range(num))))
def test_5(num): return [x for i in range(num) for x in odd_generator_2(i)]
def test_6(num): return [x for lst in map(odd_generator_2, range(num)) for x in lst]
def test_7(num): return sum((odd_generator_2(p) for p in range(num)), start=[])
num = 1_000
count = 10
print("#0:", timeit("test_0(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#1:", timeit("test_1(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#2:", timeit("test_2(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#3:", timeit("test_3(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#=========================================================")
print("#4:", timeit("test_4(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#5:", timeit("test_5(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#6:", timeit("test_6(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
print("#7:", timeit("test_7(num)",globals=globals(), number=count))
#0: 0.36987589998170733
#1: 0.4165434999158606
#2: 7.289839400094934
#3: 13.751488599926233
#=========================================================
#4: 0.2722389999544248
#5: 0.3475140000227839
#6: 0.4873567000031471
#7: 13.470793100073934
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a listcomp if you really want to. The implementation would be:

```
def test():
    return [x for lst in map(odd_generator, range(5)) if lst for x in lst]
```

or if you want to avoid `map` (and are okay with some ugliness replacing the `None`s with empty iterables):

```
def test():
    return [x for i in range(5) for x in (odd_generator(i) or ())]
```

Neither case requires the walrus, but I won't argue either of them is particularly pretty.

It would definitely make both solutions nicer if `odd_generator` always returned a sometimes-empty iterable, simplifying the code to one of:

```
def test():
    return [x for lst in map(odd_generator, range(5)) for x in lst]

def test():
    return [x for i in range(5) for x in odd_generator(i)]
```

or with `chain.from_iterable` allowing you to push it all to the C layer:

```
from itertools import chain

def test():
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(odd_generator, range(5))))
```

There's an even faster solution using `functools.reduce`+`operator.iconcat` that gets the logical effect of `sum` without the inefficiences, but it only applies when you're definitely making a new `list`, and it's more obscure; in practice, it's best to stick to `chain` and *not* preemptively convert to a `list` (the caller can always `list`ify if they want to).

---

As a side-note: Don't use `sum` to combine `list`s; it's a form of Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm (in that it's performing repeated not-in-place concatenation, which makes the work `O(n²)`, where flattening one level of a nested sequence using in-place concatenation is `O(n)`). For a simple case, consider:

```
def foo(x):
    return list(range(x))
```

Now benchmarking with IPython's `%timeit magic` (on CPython x86-64 3.10.5):

```
>>> %timeit sum(map(foo, range(10)), [])
2.28 µs ± 27.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(foo, range(10)))  # Tiny bit slower for small inputs
2.54 µs ± 13.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit sum(map(foo, range(100)), [])  # Larger input, but still fairly moderate size, takes >100x longer
255 µs ± 2.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(foo, range(100)))  # Same input processed efficiently takes less than 25x longer
61.8 µs ± 319 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: The sum did look prettier, but you're probably right. I'm a bit confused by your benchmarks, but for the rest it's great.

Comment: @Nineteendo: I'm just demonstrating in the benchmarks that repeated concatenation via `sum` seems okay when the inputs are small (it beats `chain.from_iterable` by a tiny amount), but as they grow, the cost of repeated concatenation grows *much* faster (thus the recommendation not to use `sum`).

Comment: I honestly prefer the normal timeit (see benchmarks in the question)

Comment: @Nineteendo: If you want to use the built-in `timeit` module, I'd recommend using `timeit.repeat` and taking the `min`, median or mean of the results it gives, not `timeit.timeit` alone. I'm actually a little mad at IPython here; in older versions, they took the `min` (which was usually closest to "correct", where everything longer than the `min` was a result of various artifacts, like CPU contention with other processes); mean doesn't properly exclude outliers on the high end the way `min` or median would.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (and arguably, better) to go without a walrus operator. Assuming `res` is generated by a function `f(x)` that can return None or empty results, we can combine short-circuit and sum of list for something like this:

```
sum((f(p) or [] for p in range(5)), start=[])
```

With a walrus operator, it will be:

```
sum((res for p in range(5) if (res := f(p))), start=[])
```

**Old answer:**

Generate twice as many numbers, half them (so that there are equal pairs), negate every other one:

```
[[-(i//2) if i&1 else i//2] for i in range(2*n)]
```

Alternative: sum of lists

```
sum(([[p], [-p]] for p in range(n)), start=[])
```

Comment: sum((res for p in range(5) if (res := [[p], [-p]])), start=[])

Comment: @Nineteendo the point was, it's better without a walrus operator

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify my code as much as possible. In my actual code res is derived from a function that can return None.

Comment: @Nineteendo people coming across this question will not have the same context. Can you update the question? I'll update the answer then

Comment: done, I've added an odd generator. Then you must check it's not None.